# Getting the output of a child process's "PHP Fatal Error"

Tags: php, unit-testing, fork, jenkins

I've already learned that you can't catch PHP Fatal Errors, and your script will terminate about as soon as it hits one.  I'm running a large PHP test suite (not PHPUnit, but a custom solution) on a CI server, and want to have the test pass/failures to be reported in JUnit output format.

Since way too many things in PHP are "Fatal Errors", I don't want the Fatal Error to end my test run, so my solution was to use forking, something like this:

```
foreach($tests as $test) {
    $pid = pcntl_fork();
    if ($pid) {
        $test->run();
        $test->write_junit($some_file_name);
    }
    else {
        pcntl_wait($status);
        if ($status) { //fatal error
            // from here we have no data about why it 
            // crashed, since that was in the child's memory
        }
    }
}
```

My idea was to close the STDERR in the child and have it send it's standard error to a pipe that the parent can read and save the error data into the JUnit file, but now I don't know if that's possible.  Can you change the file for STDERR?  Basically, what I want to do is like [popen](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) but without the exec() step.

Can I get the output of a child process after it died of a PHP Fatal Error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [register a shutdown function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) in the child process and check the last error when it's called. If there's an error that matches one of the fatal types (`E_ERROR`, `E_COMPILE_ERROR`, `E_CORE_ERROR`, and `E_PARSE`), write it into the JUnit file. While you cannot *recover* from a fatal error, your shutdown function is still called.

**Update:** As Pacerier points out in the comments, since `E_CORE_ERROR` is only thrown while the PHP interpreter is bootstrapping itself, it occurs before a shutdown function can be registered and cannot be trapped.

Comment: Yeah, this is actually what I'm doing.  It's a terrible hack though. To my knowledge there is no way to access the FATAL ERROR stacktrace (any message about it) from inside the shutdown function.  If that's actually possible this would totally be a solution. I really dislike PHP.

Comment: @Chad - You can get the message, code, file, and line number where it occurred using [error_get_last()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php), but that's it.

Comment: I was excited about this answer, but then I found out error_get_last isn't in PHP 5.1.  I'm marking you as best answer anyway since I didn't specify version and if someone else has this question, they can use this trick. Hopefully we'll be updating to a less ancient version of PHP in the near future.

Comment: @David, Doesn't E_CORE_ERROR only occur before our script runs?

Comment: @Pacerier - "Fatal errors that occur during PHP's initial startup." Yes, it sounds like you're correct.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find anything that would allow you to redirect stderr with an approach like the one you are using.

However, you could perhaps use `ini_set('error_log', $some_log_path)` in your child and then read the file if the child crashed to determine the error message?

Failing that, you could rewrite your code to invoke a separate single-test-runner PHP wrapper via `proc_open` and use the shell to send stderr to somewhere sane.

Comment: This could be useful, but it would be much better if instead of $some_log_path I could do it in a unix pipe instead of throwing something on the filesystem.